# Ordering a List of Objects by 'Sector %' then everything else in Order

Tags: c#, linq, .net-3.5, sql-order-by

**Scenario:** I have a list of Sectors that need to be ordered by Sector first then everything else in order.

Example:

Sector 1
Sector 2 North
Sector 2 South
Everything
From
Here
On
Ordered

**Question:** Is there a way with LINQ or some other method to ordered the list of objects this way? The object is comprised of Sector_ID and Description (the name).

Comment: What do you mean by "in order"?  If you specify an order, then you have to be specific about each field that you want to have it ordered on, if not, then the result is not deterministic (in LINQ, or in SQL for that matter) beyond what you have specified.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming this is LINQ to Objects, it's pretty easy:

```
// False comes before True, IIRC, so we want to a projection such that
// everything which starts with Sector maps to False, and everything else
// maps to True.
var query = list.OrderBy(x => !x.Description.StartsWith("Sector")) 
                .ThenBy(x => x.Description);
```

Mind you, I may have misunderstood the question. It may be you just want something like:

```
var query = list.OrderBy(x => x.SectorId)
                .ThenBy(x => x.Description);
```

Your sample data only contains one column, but then you've talked about two... if you could give more detail in the question, it would be easier to give you a useful answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to sort your list by providing a Comparison to the Sort method for your object that would compare the Sector_ID first and then the Description.